# Ubuntu/Xfce disable global shortcuts for specific application

Tags: c, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, x11, xfce

This question has been asked by someone else on a different stackexchange site, but has not received any answers, hopefully more traffic here will get an answer.

I'm running a java gui application and would like that when this application has focus, it handles all keyboard events, including ones which would normally be intercepted by the window manager (eg alt-left which changes desktop). I do not want to have to change all relevant shortcuts manually.

If there is no configuration way to do this, would a possible solution be to write a low level X windows application in C which could attach itself to a specified window and intercept all keypresses BEFORE the window manager, passing them through to the specified window ?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have up to now is:

1. Install very light weight wm like 'twm': (sudo apt-get install twm)
2. Kick off a concurrent X session with no wm: xinit /usr/bin/xterm -- :2
3. Switch to new X session: control-alt-F8
4. Start twm in xterm within new session: twm &
5. Run program, enjoy programs shortcuts and be happy, switching back to other X session with control-alt-F7